# How to avoid structured-subtyping in conditional type?

Tags: typescript

I am matching on some standard error in type-statement, like:

```
type MatchOutput<T> = T extends EvalError ? EvalError : T extends Error ? Error : { DUMMY: true };
```

However, when invoking `MatchOutput<Error>`, output is incorrectly solved as a `EvalError`.

this is because of structured-subtyping:

But I want it to be just a `Error`. How can I achieve that behavior?

```
type MatchOutput<T> = T extends EvalError ? EvalError : T extends Error ? Error : { DUMMY: true };

declare const a: MatchOutput<EvalError>; // expected: EvalError
declare const b: MatchOutput<Error>; // expected: Error
declare const c: MatchOutput<string> // expected: { DUMMY: true }
```

Comment: Well, `EvalError` has the exact same properties as `Error` so it can not be differentiated from `Error` the only way to differentiate them is to use `instanceof` operator

Comment: You can't "avoid" structural typing. `EvalError` and `Error` are identical types in TS, despite having different names. TS is at liberty to display `Error` or `EvalError` as it pleases. Does `type MatchOutput<T> = T extends Error ? T : ⋯` work for you? That should display the same type name as the input. If not, does merging a dummy property into `EvalError` so they're not identical work for you? Both are shown in [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mLAEbW). If that fully addresses the question I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?